# Multi-stage form in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I want to build a simple multi-stage registration process in Laravel 5.5, without having to resort to JavaScript, but I'm not sure if it's possible.

My routes are fairly simple:

```
Route::get('/stage1', 'UserController@showWelcome')->name('welcome');
Route::post('/stage1', 'UserController@validateWelcome');

Route::get('/stage2', 'UserController@create')->name('register');
Route::post('/stage2', 'UserController@store');
```

In the **UserController**...

`@showWelcome` -> `return view('stage1')`
`@validateWelcome` -> validates input then `return view('stage2', compact('request'))`

`@create` -> `return view('stage2')`
`@store` -> validates the input, saves to DB then `return view('stagesComplete')`

**The problem**
Everything works perfectly except when there's a validation error during stage 2. The page is submitted but it shows the error messages on `stage1`.

I've ensured that the `stage1` form POSTs to `/stage1`, and the same for `/stage2` (it POSTs to `/stage2`).

I've tried *redirecting* to `/stage2` with `@validateWelcome`, but of course you can't POST with a redirect.

Am I missing something, or is it just not possible?

Comment: Why whould you show the stage 1 in the create of stage 2 ? i think that is the problem if you have  stage2.blade.php there will be no problems !!

Comment: you may use bootstrap wizard http://vinceg.github.io/twitter-bootstrap-wizard/

Comment: @KhanShahrukh OP: "**without** having to resort to JavaScript".

Comment: @Maraboc Tried it, it didn't work. I've updated the question to reflect it, as it seemed to be causing confusion.

Comment: my bad @Jeffrey

Comment: When you have a validation error you redirect to stage 1 or stage 2? or it's better to show us a code example of the `@store` method !!

Comment: @Maraboc I don't want to overwhelm the question with code. I've updated the question though, if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you should create:

```
GET step1 - show form
POST step1 - validate and redirect to step2 
GET step2 - show form
POST step2 - validate and save data in database/whatever
```

when POST step1 is fine, you can add data to session and redirect to step2, when you run POST step2 and data is invalid there won't be any problem because you wil have GET step2 action

Comment: Adding the data to the session rather than POSTing it and then redirecting was the key.